# Updating selected array element after deleting the element from a filtered ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have a list of users where you click on a user to select it and put the element into an object $scope.selectedMember when selected. I'm using ng-repeat with a search box filter. The important thing is that $scope.selectedMember should always be populated with a member.

Problem is that i'm trying to overcome:
 - splicing the last user out needs to automatically select the last user in the filtered array, even if it's filtered some members out with the search.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input ng-model="search"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, member) in members | filter:search | orderBy :'-name'">
        <li ng-class="{active: retActive(key)}"
            ng-click="selectThis($index)">
            name: {{member.name}} key: {{key}}
                <button ng-click="deleteThis(key)">delete</button>
        </li>
    </div>
    Selected member name: {{selectedMember.name}}
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp', []);

function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.members = [
                          {"name":"a", "viewIndex":0},
                          {"name":"b", "viewIndex":1},
                          {"name":"bb", "viewIndex":2},
                          {"name":"bb", "viewIndex":3},
                          {"name":"c", "viewIndex":4},
                          {"name":"d", "viewIndex":5},
                          {"name":"e", "viewIndex":6}
                         ];

    $scope.activeIndex = 0;
    $scope.selectedMember = $scope.members[0];

    $scope.selectThis = function (index) {
        $scope.activeIndex = index;
        //put array member into new object
        $scope.selectedMember = $scope.members[index];  
    }

    //splice the selected member from the array  
    $scope.deleteThis = function (index) {
        $scope.members.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.selectThis(index);  
    }

    //angular copy and push member to the array
    $scope.duplicateThis = function (index) {

    }

    // change class if member is active
    $scope.retActive = function (index) {
        return $scope.activeIndex == index;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.active {
    color:blue;
}
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0lska/o7z8qu09/20/)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you try to rephrase it.

Comment: I'll try to rephrase it. Can you tell me which part is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you are passing $index to selectThis($index). When you filter data, the loop's $index no longer represents the actual index of an item in the array - so you should pass selectThis a key, not $index.

Comment: the key is updated as well when the filter is applied. I know i can use members.indexOf(member) in the html but is there a cleaner way to pass the actual array index to the controller? Also, I need to have some reference to the indices of the filtered array so that upon deletion of the last member, the $index of the filtered array is used instead of the indexOf() the member. This is because the array is in reverse order after its filtered and it will be confusing for a user if they delete the last member and then what looks like the first member is selected next.